# why the {% if post.is_liked %} doesn't work in home.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have passed the context of is_liked to from the PostListView to the home template, but why the `if post.is_liked` the statement doesn't work? I have an `like_post` function that when the user liked the post, the `is_liked will equal to true` and text will turn from not liked to liked. But why the if statements did not work(only showed not liked) in the template with no error messages? Or I have tried to change the if statements to `{% post.user.is_liked %}` and `{% user.is_liked %}`. But it still didn't work, what is the problem? thanks

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def like_post(request):   # post like
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10
    is_liked = False

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data()
        posts = context['posts']
        for post in posts:
            if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                context['is_liked'] = True
            return context


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    is_liked = False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = context['post']
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            context['is_liked'] = True
        return context
```

home.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if post.is_liked %} #I want to get whether the post is_liked by user
                <h5>liked</h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5>not liked</h5>
            {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Because you did not assign these on the post. You simply made a context that contains *one* variable `is_liked`, hence `post.is_liked` does not exists, only `is_liked`, and this is not related to a specific post.

Comment: what should I do if I want to assign the is_liked in a specific post? because I have done this to the PostDetailView and it worked fine as detailview just showed a specific post. But in the home view, I don't know how to assign it. Thanks

Comment: post the relevant models...

Comment: Sorry, I have added relevant models now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the queryset such that the `Post` objects that arise from this have an extra attribute `.is_liked` with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            is_liked=Exists(Post.likes.through.objects.filter(
                user_id=self.request.user.id,
                post_id=OuterRef('pk')
            ))
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have received an error `NameError at /
name 'request' is not defined` Why does that happen?

Comment: @LouisGlenn: yes, the request object is an attribute of `self`, so `self.request.user.id`.